# Simulating mouse scroll ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say I want to backup every image from a website so I write a simple script

```
require "open-uri"
require "pathname"

unless ARGV[0]
 puts "Usage: ruby imageScrape.rb <URL>"
 exit
end

url = ARGV[0].strip
begin
    open(url, "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5;     Windows´98)") do |source|
        source.each_line do |x|
             if x =~ / height="[0-9][0-9][0-9]" src="(.+.    [jpeg|gif])"\s+/
                 name = $1.split('"').first
                 name = url + name if Pathname.new(name).absolute?
                 copy = name.split('/').last
                 File.open(copy, 'wb') do |f|
                     f.write(open(name).read)
                 end
             end
         end
     end
rescue => e
 puts "Error"
 puts e
end
```

But the problem is that this website loads more content only after scrolling mouse wheel. So after running a script I get 5 images instead of 150. Is there a way to dwonload them all?

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems here.

First is the `open` call returns HTML as a string. You should use something like [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) to parse that and extract all the `img` tags. That's usually really simple:

```
Nokogiri::HTML(source.read).css('img').each do |img_tag|
  href = img_tag.attr('src')

  # ... Other code to fetch and save image
end
```

The second problem is that the server has only sent you one page of content, the rest is loaded with JavaScript. Simulating a "mouse scroll" is futile here because there's no browser to simulate it in. Instead, have a look at what that JavaScript is doing, either by reading the source or looking at what network calls are made, and emulate those in Ruby. Often you'll see calls with stuff like `?page=2` or `?offset=50` at the end of the URL. You just need to iterate over those until you get blank results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To be specific the site that I've been writing about is soup.io. It doesn't change URL adress while scrolling. Also I don't want to download all images but only those which has three digital height, as you can see in my script

Comment: You can always filter just as you've done now, but instead of using a regular expression, just use Nokogiri: `attr('height')` is all you need. If it's an "infinite scroll" site, pay close attention to the network calls made using a tool like Chrome's "Network" inspector. The URL in the browser will not change, but AJAX calls are made in the background.